# Linux awk command with pipe

Tags: linux, awk

Can anyone tell me what the below linux command does:

```
tail -5 test.log | grep 'Start Calculate' | awk '{print $1}'
```

I know `tail -5 test.log | grep 'Start Calculate'` looks for the 5 last lines containing 'Start Calculate' in test.log. But then I don't get what awk does?

Comment: Simplified version : `tail -5 test.log | awk '/Start Calculate/{print $1}'`

Comment: @sat it is not a simplified version, it is a better version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tail -5 test.log` take the 5 last lines of the `test.log` file

then

`grep 'Start Calculate'` filter to keep only the lines containing 'Start Calculate'

then

`awk '{print $1}'` take the first column of each line (using `space` as the separator between columns)

Answer (score 0):

the `awk` command is printing the first whitespace-separated field of each line.

Comment: white or tab space separated